# How do I count a number of different dates in the same column?

Tags: excel, function, excel-2010

I'm currently working on a project for a business in which I have to display how much we make per hour and per day (i'm using pivot tables):
My first column is "Dates"
The second one is "Hours"
The third one is "Turnover"

The idea is that the hours column is as followed:

```
<8:00

8:00-9:00

9:00-10:00

...

17:00-18:00

18:00<
```

Which means that my dates column include 13 times the same date for each day (I want it to be count as 1 and not 13)

The idea is to display, the sum of days opened per month and per year (in order to display a pivot table graph)

You'll find enclosed a screenshot that shows the sheet, column 2 and 3 are not part of the problem.

[Excel Sheet example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wdkq.png)

Comment: So why not `=COUNT(A:A)/13`

Answer (score 1):

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(A:A,A:A)>0,1))
```

counts the distinct numbers, which Excel considers dates to be, in column `A`.

Source: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/count-unique-values-among-duplicates-8d9a69b3-b867-490e-82e0-a929fbc1e273